# TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined nodejs & mongoclient

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to get information from my meteor mongo database and display it as a json on my web page but i get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined` and i don't know why.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db;
// Initialize connection once
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:3001", function(err, database) {
if(err) //console.log(err);
console.log(database);
  db = database;
  // Start the application after the database connection is ready
  app.listen(3001);
  console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});

// middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  // do logging
  //console.log('Something is happening.');
  next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});
router.route('/subscribers')
  app.get("/api/subscribers", function (req, res) {

    db.subs.find({}, function(err, docs) {
      docs.each(function(err, doc) {
        if(doc) {
          res.json(doc);
        }
        else {
          res.end();
        }

      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: check whether your DB is connected or not because your app.port ant DB port are running on  the same port

Comment: According to the docs, you should invoke the `collection` method on your `db` object to access the collection. 

i.e. `db.collection('subs').find(...)`

Comment: thanks @AhmadBaktashHayeri it was that the problem ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is right here:

```
db.subs.find({}, function(err, docs) {
```

There is no `subs` property in your `db` object. Check to make sure your database is loading properly and has the `subs` property. If you need to account for the case where there is no `subs` property, you can do something like this:

```
  app.get("/api/subscribers", function (req, res) {
    if (db.subs) {
      db.subs.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        docs.each(function(err, doc) {
          if(doc) {
            res.json(doc);
          }
          else {
            res.end();
          }

        });
      });
     }
  });
```

Comment: subs is my collection so how should i do to get a find on my collection called subs ?

Comment: It looks like you are doing that, provided that `subs` exists. The problem is that `subs` doesn't exist. `subs` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `subs` exists. It is because `subs` is undefined at line:

```
db.subs.find({}, function(err, docs) {
```